# Silverlight C# image object

Tags: c#, silverlight

Hope you can help. Stuck on a simple problem for some, I'm a noob. What in trying to do is get an image objects in Silverlight/C# to drop randomly from the top of the canvas, at the moment its going right to left.

This is the from the object class.

```
namespace LOLWordGame
{
    public class LetterA : ContentControl, IGameEntity
    {
        private int speed = 0;

        public LetterA()
        {
            Image LetterImage = new Image();
            LetterImage.Height = 45;
            LetterImage.Width = 45;
            LetterImage.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("images/a.png", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));
            this.Content = LetterImage;

            Random random = new Random();
            Canvas.SetLeft(this, -20); 
            Canvas.SetTop(this, random.Next(250, 850)); //randomly
            speed = random.Next(1, 5);
        }   

        public void Update(Canvas c)
        {
            Move(Direction.Down);
            if (Canvas.GetLeft(this) < 100)
            {
                c.Children.Remove(this);
            }
        }

        public void Move(Direction direction)
        {
            Canvas.SetLeft(this, Canvas.GetLeft(this) - speed);
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

For a solution: maybe you should use the [**Canvase.SetTop Method**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.canvas.settop%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) instead of the SetLeft method? Hope this helps.

Secondary.. I'm sure following code is not the solution to your problem but I refactored it a bit. Try using [**collection initializers**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb397680.aspx). You have a method `Move` that you only call once and the method has only one line of code: no reason to make that a method in my opinion. Also the method takes in a parameter but you do not use it inside the method.

```
public class LetterA : ContentControl, IGameEntity
{
    private int speed = 0;

    public LetterA()
    {
        var letterImage = new Image()
        {
            Height = 45,
            Width = 45,
            Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("images/a.png", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute))
        };
        Content = letterImage;

        var random = new Random();
        Canvas.SetLeft(this, -20); 
        Canvas.SetTop(this, random.Next(250, 850));
        speed = random.Next(1, 5);
    }   

    public void Update(Canvas c)
    {
        Canvas.SetLeft(this, Canvas.GetLeft(this) - speed);
        if (Canvas.GetLeft(this) < 100)
            c.Children.Remove(this);
    }
}
```